# How to check all instance of browsers are closed using HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, cookies

We need to implement sessions management using cookie. I am able to set timeout,

```
window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(myFunction, 4000);
};
```

`myFunction` gets called after 4000 mSec, but I want `myFunction` should also gets called when ***all the instances*** of browser gets closed.

Now, using `onbeforeunload` I can get event when browser is closed, but same event I get when ,

1. browser is refreshed
2. tab is closed, browser is still running
3. Browser is closed but other instances of browser is running

Is there any event in HTML/JavaScript which gets fire when all the instances of browser gets closed.

Comment: No; you only get to know when *your* site is unloaded: why would you want to know what, or should you have any access to whatever, else the user might be doing in their browsers?

Comment: @DavidThomas I want to implement session management. I only have access to cookies, how can I do that without knowing about state of all the remaining browsers?

Comment: It doesn't matter why you want it, however noble your intentions doesn't make it possible for you to do this. You can only make guesses at disconnections or browser-closures if there's no contact from the client after a fixed number of attempts over a specific period of time.

Comment: @DavidThomas May be my question is too straight. Can you please suggest is there any way to implement my own session management?

Answer (score 0):

When all the instances of browsers are closed, so do the Javascript Runtime and there is no way to parse any JS code into action.